# Neo4j Lucene fulltext search

Tags: neo4j, lucene, cypher, full-text-search

I create an fulltext index:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX skillAndTranslationsNamesAndDescriptions FOR (n:Skill|Translation) ON EACH [n.name, n.description]
```

Also, added a node with name = `bash-variables`

I'm able to successfully query this node with the following query:

```
match (s:Skill {name: 'bash-variables'}) return s;
```

Now, I'd like to query this node by Neo4j Cypher fulltext search:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("skillAndTranslationsNamesAndDescriptions", "bash-var*") YIELD node, score
OPTIONAL MATCH (node)-[:ALIAS_FOR*]->(skillForAlias:Skill)
OPTIONAL MATCH (node)<-[:CONTAINS]-(skillForTrans:Skill)
RETURN node.name, node.id, skillForAlias.name, skillForAlias.id, skillForTrans.name, skillForTrans.id, score, labels(node)
LIMIT 100
```

and it returns nothing.

I think the reason is in the Lucene special character `-` but I don't knowhow to properly handle this. Simply escaping this with `\-` didn't help.

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the "whitespace" analyzer:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX skillAndTranslationsNamesAndDescriptions 
FOR (n:Skill|Translation) ON EACH [n.name, n.description] 
OPTIONS { indexConfig: {`fulltext.analyzer`: 'whitespace'}}
```

Comment: Found another issue with this approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72943818/neo4j-cypher-code-complete-feature-implementation

Comment: Using the Whitespace Analyzer works for me, but I have to manually handle character case since it doesn't perform automatic case conversion